# Search in a nested array and return a value from that array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an API endpoint that returns a JSON response with a bunch of game ids. That response looks like this (and yes, it is heavily snipped).

```
{
"finished": [
        {
        "game_id": 8
        },
        {
        "game_id": 9
        },
        {
        "game_id": 11
        }
    ],
"unfinished": [
        {
        "game_id": 12
        },
        {
        "game_id": 13
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to achieve probably needs a bunch separate functions. But I want to search the array for a specific ID, that is user inputed. And depending if it is in the "finished" or "unfinished", return the value from that key.

Lets say that I want to search the array for ID of `13`. That ID would be found in "unfinished". And if that is the case, I want to return the first ID in the "unfinished" array, ID 12.

If I would search the array for ID `9`, that would be found in "finished", then return that ID (`9`).

If I would search the array for ID `12`, that would be found in "unfinished", return the first ID from unfinished, ID 12.

Hope this makes sense.

I have been making some test just with searching the array, but no luck at all

```
const test = _.findKey(game_ids, function(o) { return o.game_id == 8; });
```

Comment: So, if finished, return id, if unfinished return id of 1st item in unfinished array. What happens if nothing is found?

Comment: Exactly! And if nothing is found, maybe return the first ID of unfinished again. Haven't thought about that situation =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.find()` with a short circuit to try the unfinished if the game id is not found in finished, and if nothing found return the 1st of finished:

```js
const data = {"finished":[{"game_id":8},{"game_id":9},{"game_id":11}],"unfinished":[{"game_id":12},{"game_id":13}]};

const findId = (game_id) => _.find(data.finished, { game_id }) || (_.find(data.unfinished, { game_id }) && data.unfinished[0]) || data.unfinished[0];

console.log(findId(13));

console.log(findId(9));

console.log(findId(200));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure JavaScript solution:

```
var response = {"finished":[{"game_id":8},{"game_id":9},{"game_id":11}],"unfinished":[{"game_id":12},{"game_id":13}]};

function find(response, value) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < response.finished.length; i++) {
        if (response.finished[i].game_id === value) {
            return value;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < response.unfinished.length; i++) {
        if (response.unfinished[i].game_id === value) {
            return response.unfinished[0].game_id;
        }
    }

    return undefined;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful and educational! And it works to =)

Answer (score 1):

So at a basic level you need to iterate through two arrays to find some value.

You mentioned lodash which has a [great `find` utility function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#find). With this function in hand, you would call this function twice, once for each array. Make sure to handle the case where no game is found.

ex:

```
var targetVal = userInput; 
game_id = _.find(apiResponse. finished, { game_id: targetVal })
```